# Electron opening every link in browser instead of electron itself

Tags: javascript, events, electron

I wanted to open an external link not in electron but in the browser. Therefore I implemented this code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.href.startsWith('http')) {
   event.preventDefault();
   shell.openExternal(event.target.href);
 }
});
```

My problem is now that every link that I create, opens in the browser.
e.g.

`<a href="http://google.com">foo</a>` <-wanted behaviour to open in browser

`<a href="#">bar</a>`  <- not wanted behaviour to open in browser

How can I get it to just open the external link in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="#"></a>` is actually `href="http://localhost:X000/#"`
so the if condition is always true.
Replace your code with this and it should work:

```
    const { app, shell, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1300,
      height: 800,
    });

    // Load your React app or any other HTML which creates your Electron app content
    mainWindow.loadFile("./build/index.html");

    mainWindow.webContents.on("new-window", function(event, url) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // This will open a new Electron window to load the url.
      shell.openExternal(url);
    });
```